# Graphing two variables into one line chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-area

Sorry in advance if I'm not very clear in the explanation of my problem (I'm very new to R) but I am trying to graph 2 variables (Average cereal yield, Average land area change) into the same area chart to show the difference between cereal yield growth and land area change between a date range but I can't figure out how to get it to work the way I want it to. Here's a picture of my initial dataset with respective variables:

```
  
year    meancereal   meanland
<chr>    <dbl>        <dbl>
1961    100.0000    100.0000        
1962    107.6528    100.9864        
1963    108.3420    101.4125        
1964    109.5492    104.1026        
1965    111.8808    105.2984        
1966    110.3679    106.5562        
1967    117.0725    109.7375        
1968    117.5337    112.8811        
1969    120.2902    114.9961        
1970    120.5337    114.4149
```

I've tried converting to a longer dataset so that instead of having 2 separate columns  I just have one for Averages and one for Values:

```
 year      Avg        value
<chr>      <chr>      <dbl>
1961    meancereal  100.0000        
1961    meanland    100.0000        
1962    meancereal  107.6528        
1962    meanland    100.9864        
1963    meancereal  108.3420        
1963    meanland    101.4125        
1964    meancereal  109.5492        
1964    meanland    104.1026        
1965    meancereal  111.8808        
1965    meanland    105.2984
```

This is the code I've written so far:

```
landchangeC<-land_use %>%
  filter(year>1960,year<2015)%>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise( meancereal= mean(cereal_yield_index, na.rm=TRUE),
             meanland=mean(land_area_change, na.rm=TRUE))


landchangeC<-landchangeC%>%
  pivot_longer(meancereal:meanland, names_to="Avg", values_to="value")


landchangeC%>%
  ggplot(aes(year, value, color=Avg))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_area()
```

After I run the code It just shows a blank graph:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: (I suggested an edit that includes the output of `dput` on what I think is your data. Please confirm it's close-enough. It doesn't have to be the same exact values, but the types and ranges need to be right.)

Comment: I don't get your image when I plot your data. When I remove `geom_area()`, it a two-line chart, which seems appropriate given the data. Notes about `geom_area`: (1) it defaults to a y minimum of 0, which completely changes the scale; (2) the `fill=` is defaulting for me to black, you might `color=Avg, fill=Avg`; (3) by default, it is stacking the values, not raw values, so it's a sand-plot. Bottom line, I can't reproduce that plot with that data.

Comment: @r2evans, I removed geom_area() so that I was only running geom_line() but the graph is still blank. I also received the message:  
'geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?'

Comment: One guess: Your year variable is a character. Try adding the group aes, i.e. `ggplot(aes(year, value, color=Avg, group = Avg))`.

Comment: @stefan, problem solved! thanks heaps